# Random Forest on financial time-serie?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning

Is it okay to apply Random Forest to a non-stationary financial serie? Or would it be correct to first difference the serie and then apply Random Forest to the new serie?

Comment: what are the predictors ? if they are past values of the series, then you're better off using first differences ( of logs ) which are the returns. This is because return correlations are real whereas the price correlations are spurious. By this I mean that price series are correlated by definition so any correlations aren't  real. Returns are not correlated by definition so, if they're correlated, it's a real correlation. If you're predictors are  not past values, it still probably makes more sense to use returns but, in that case, the problem I described will be less of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the RF to the financial time series rather than the first order log diff then your model will overfit by learning the price levels.

I would not do it that way.